# Google OAuth2 returns Bad Request when logged with multiple accounts

Tags: google-oauth

When I'm logged in google with multiple accounts

[image]

and i'm trying to authorize myself at https://stackoverflow.com/users/login (or any other site using OAuth2)

[image]

I get a `Bad Request - Error 400`

[image]

This doesn't happen when i'm in incognito mode

[image]

A sample request is the following

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=717762328687-p17pldm5fteklla3nplbss3ai9slta0a.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile+email&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fstackauth.com%2fauth%2foauth2%2fgoogle&state=%7b%22sid%22%3a1%2c%22st%22%3a%221435c1882569148a8513b8e5ba7f747ac7821aaf558cbb1a28dd11c5c3cb358b%22%2c%22ses%22%3a%22354093ee65ee44e8a24582c78bdb7127%22%7d&response_type=code
```

There are other similar questions like [Google oauth2 and 400 bad request: Bug on Google side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212728/google-oauth2-and-400-bad-request-bug-on-google-side) but are old and marked as fixed bugs.
How could I fix this?
Should I add some other parameters to trigger the account selection?