# Authentication returns 400 and "something went wrong" but works in incognito mode

Tags: authentication, bad-request

I've been developing authentication flow on php lib: googleapis/google-api-php-client v2.9.1. Everything was working fine, but after some time while trying to authenticate the google started displaying "Something went wrong" message with 500 in console and after pressing next button "The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know." with 400 code. But everything works fine if I use incognito mode.

The similar issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212728/google-oauth2-and-400-bad-request-bug-on-google-side) and it only occurs on chrome and when user is logged in into several google accounts, works fine if you delete accounts.google.com domain cookies or use Incognito mode.

Is there a way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question the solution was quite simple - **after you apply for verification and Google verifies your app this issue disappears without any additional efforts.**

I assume that main issue is that if you have multiple google accounts connected to your chrome and you add only some of them to an app as a tester or etc. Google can't handle not connected accounts for security measures and returns an error. Of course the error itself could be handled little bit better.

I hope this answer saves some time for everyone else who is struggling with this issue.